# How to stop execve from exiting original program

Tags: c, io, pipe, fork, io-redirection

I have written my own shell and wrote a function that handles triple piping but I have an issue with my shell exiting after execve. I believe the issue is that I need to fork an extra time? but I am not entirely sure where, since this executes the piped programs perfectly. Also there is no use of wait(2) in this implementation, not sure if that has something to do with it too. Thanks

```
int fd[2];
int fd2[2];

if (pipe(fd) == -1)
{
    perror("ERROR CREATING PIPE");
    return;
}

pid_t pid = fork();

if (args4[0] != NULL)
{
    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
            printf("%s\n", "fail to fork");
            return;
        case 0:
            if (pipe(fd2) == -1)
            {
                perror("ERROR CREATING PIPE");
                return;
            }
            switch(pid = fork())
            {
                case -1:
                    printf("%s\n", "fail to fork");
                    return;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    if ( dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 )
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", "fail to dup");
                        return;
                    }
                    close(fd2[0]);
                    close(fd2[1]);
                    execve(args2[0], args2, environ);
                    exit(1);
                default:
                    if ( dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 )
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", "fail to dup");
                        return;
                    }
                    if ( dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 )
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", "fail to dup");
                        return;
                    }
                    close(fd2[0]);
                    close(fd2[1]);
                    execve(args3[0], args3, environ);
                    exit(2);
            }
            exit(3);

        default:
            if ( dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", "fail to dup");
                return;
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            printf("%s\n", "4");
            execve(args4[0], args4, environ);
            exit(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fork for every subprocess you intend to invoke.

Comment: yes I understand, I am having trouble figuring out which process to fork. I think it would be execve(args2[0], args2, environ) since it is the last process to invoke. I have tried forking before all 3 execs but it doesn't help.

Comment: nevermind im stupid. Thank you. Forked the first process for args4

Comment: error message should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   `fprintf( stderr, ...)` does this.  When the error is a returned indication from a system function, then use `perror()` so the reason the OS thinks the error occurred is also output.

Answer (score 2):

You have forked twice so you have 3 processes. Each of them is replaced by the respective process created by execve. You will never get to the exit() statements since execve() does not return (on success). Here is your code rewritten without the pipes (you clearly understand how to set up the pipes) and without the unnecessary statements:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid) {
    execve(args4[0], args4, environ);
}
else {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        execve(args3[0], args3, environ);
    }
    else {
        execve(args2[0], args2, environ);
    }
}
```

With the rewritten code above you can more easily see that you will get three processes like this:

args2[0] | args3[0] | arg4[0]